# How to have drop down menu selections show concatenation of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a part number creator type engine in which the user can create their own part numbers based on the drop down menu values given as well as manually entry of text. I want it to take the values the user has inputted and compile it into a part number with no spacing.  I seem to be stuck in the JavaScript portion of this that calls the function to do this...

```js
//I want to use a function like this - if there is a value 
function FillSeries(f) {
  if(f.completepart.checked == true) {
    f.ser_sel.value = f.finishedser_sel.value; //finishedser_sel would be the place holder for the value of ser_sel in the concantenated part
    f.cap_sel.value = f.finishedcap_sel.value; //finishedcap_sel would be the place holder for the value of cap_sel in the concantenated part
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<fieldset>
<table id="tbl_sel" class="tables" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="fst">SERIES</th>
<th>CAP</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><select id="ser_sel" class="txt">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="620">620</option>
<option value="621">621</option>
</select></td>
<td><input id="cap_sel" class="txt hd" maxlength="3" type="text" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
<!--not sure where to put this - inside or outside the form -->
<input type="checkbox" name="completepart" onclick="FillSeries(this.form)">
<em>Check this box if you are done creating a part number.</em>
<br><br>
<!-- I want the part number to pull the fields together into one line - all together with no spacing -->
<b>Finished Part Number</b>
<br><br>
<input class="txt" id="finishedser_sel">
<input class="txt" id="finishedcap_sel">
```

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: *"seem to be stuck"* isn't a technical problem description. What is the actual problem and question?

Comment: There's a "Tidy" button when you are editing the snippet which should help with @singe's suggestion. It's not entirely clear what problem you're having. If you want to concatenate, use the concatenate operator, `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move those fields into the form, if you want `this.form` to point to the form. Note that in your code, you are setting the value of the `select` to the value of the text box, which seems backward. In this snippet, I've reversed the order.

```js
//I want to use a function like this - if there is a value 
function FillSeries(f) {
  if (f.completepart.checked == true) {
    f.finishedser_sel.value = f.ser_sel.value; //finishedser_sel would be the place holder for the value of ser_sel in the concantenated part
    f.finishedcap_sel.value = f.cap_sel.value; //finishedcap_sel would be the place holder for the value of cap_sel in the concantenated part
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <table id="tbl_sel" class="tables" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="fst">SERIES</th>
          <th>CAP</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="ser_sel" class="txt">
              <option value=""></option>
              <option value="620">620</option>
              <option value="621">621</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="cap_sel" class="txt hd" maxlength="3" type="text" />
          </td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
  <!--not sure where to put this - inside or outside the form -->
  <input type="checkbox" name="completepart" onclick="FillSeries(this.form)">
  <em>Check this box if you are done creating a part number.</em>
  <br>
  <br>
  <!-- I want the part number to pull the fields together into one line - all together with no spacing -->
  <b>Finished Part Number</b>
  <span id="wholepart"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input class="txt" id="finishedser_sel">
  <input class="txt" id="finishedcap_sel">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click the checkBox, you send to your function (this.form).

(this) is your input, so this.form doesnt exist.

> "message": "TypeError: f is null",

Comment: Actually, `input` elements should have [a property called `form` whose value is the `id` of the containing `form` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form), at least it HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Use event listeners to watch the input and select boxes for change and then assign the values to the other input elements like so:

```js
var part1 = "";
var part2 = "";
 
var selectBox = document.getElementById('ser_sel');
selectBox.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    part1 = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById('finishedser_sel').value = event.target.value;
    
})
var inputBox = document.getElementById('cap_sel');
inputBox.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    part2 = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById('finishedcap_sel').value = event.target.value;
    
})
function FillSeries(f) {
  document.getElementById('allTogetherNow').value = (part1 + '-' + part2);
  
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
<fieldset>
<table id="tbl_sel" class="tables" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="fst">SERIES</th>
<th>CAP</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><select id="ser_sel" class="txt">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="620">620</option>
<option value="621">621</option>
</select></td>
<td><input id="cap_sel" class="txt hd" maxlength="3" type="text" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
</fieldset>
</form>
<!--not sure where to put this - inside or outside the form -->
<input type="checkbox" name="completepart" onclick="FillSeries(this.form)">
<em>Check this box if you are done creating a part number.</em>
<br><br>
<!-- I want the part number to pull the fields together into one line - all together with no spacing -->
<b>Finished Part Number</b>
<br><br>
<input class="txt" id="finishedser_sel">
<input class="txt" id="finishedcap_sel">

<br /><br />
Finished Part# <br />
<input class="txt" id="allTogetherNow">
```

Comment: sould use keydown on the text input because change is triggered only on blur.